# Is there a way to dial down the OData Service reflection provider?

Tags: c#, wcf-data-services, odata, iqueryable

This is a continuation of an issue I'm still experiencing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9091034/how-can-you-expose-a-multi-layer-model-that-has-derived-classes-and-members-for).  I'm trying to prevent the `OData` reflection provider from trying to expose ALL of the CLR classes in my assembly.

Consider the following CLR class:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Guid FooID { get; set; }
    public string FooName { get; set; }
}
```

And the following class to expose `Foo` as an `IQueryable` collection:

```
public class MyEntities 
{ 
    public IQueryable<Foo> Foos 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return DataManager.GetFoos().AsQueryable<Foo>(); 
        } 
    }
}
```

And the following `DataService` class:

```
public class MyDataService : DataService<MyEntities> 
{ 
    public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config) 
    { 
        config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("Foos", EntitySetRights.All); 
        config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V2; 
    } 
}
```

This all works hunkey dorey and the `DataService` can display a collection of `Foo`.  But if change `Foo` to extend a very simple base object such as:

```
public class Foo : MyObjectBase
{
    public Guid FooID { get; set; } 
    public string FooName { get; set; }
}
```

Then (even though I'm only trying to expose 1 collection), the reflection provider grabs ALL objects that extend `MyObjectBase`, causing loads of errors.

The base class is a simple abstract class that implements a number of interfaces and provides another property such as:

```
public abstract class MyObjectBase: IDataObject, IDataErrorInfo, INotifyPropertyChanged, IDisposable
{
    public virtual Guid ID { get; set; }
}
```

Even putting `IgnoreProperties` on any public properties here doesn't help.  Is there any way to dial down what the reflection provider is doing?

Comment: I had the same problem and I was not able to find good solution. I ended up with doubling-up of the MyObjectBase properties directly in Foo.

Comment: Ugh, not really an option with the couple hundred CLR classes in this project.  Still working on a custom provider route.

Comment: True, I only had a couple. You can have MyObjectBaseOdata and MyObjectBaseEverythingElse I guess...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set:

```
config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("TypeNotAccessible", EntitySetRights.All);
```

to

```
config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("TypeNotAccessible", EntitySetRights.None);
```

On any classes you don't want accessible. I do this using the help of a custom attribute that indicates the rights I want for a particular class. This in combination with looping over all known types (that implement my attribute), makes it possible to do this without explicit code to set each class individually.

Comment: +1 thanks M.  I was trying to turn off the rights on some of the classes.  Trouble is, all of the DAL classes have the same name as the corresponding BLL classes I want (different namespace).  Can you specify a full or partial namespace in SetEntityAccessRule?

Comment: I've never had to do so and the MSDN docs don't specify what is legal so I'd recommend trying it and seeing what happens. This probably isn't the answer you were looking for though.

Comment: Using SetEntitySetAccessRule on unwanted classes doesn't seem to help in general.  I even tried turning all access off `config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.None);` and still get the same errors of not finding those types in the data context.

Comment: I guess it is possible that my attempts have been without success, but according to the docs, "Denies all rights to access data." Unfortunately I'm not in a place to test it (my work VPN is down and I don't have enough interest in it to create one from scratch)

Comment: @DaveClemmer - [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792162/odata-wcf-service-hide-an-element) is a related question that might help.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to find a way to dial down the reflection provider with a rich data model.  I ended up building a custom provider as indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9091034/how-can-you-expose-a-multi-layer-model-that-has-derived-classes-and-members-for).

If someone provides a way to dial down the reflection provider, I'll accept that answer.